# Undefined reference to CreateCompatibleBitmap@12 with OpenSSL 1.0.2

Tags: windows, random, openssl, windows-10

This is the code I use in Codeblocks on Windows 10 with OpenSSL. But there are some errors.

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
int main()
{
    RSA *r;
    int bits=512,ret;
    unsigned long e=RSA_3;
    BIGNUM *bne;
    r=RSA_generate_key(bits,e,NULL,NULL);
    RSA_print_fp(stdout,r,11);
    RSA_free(r);
    bne=BN_new();
    ret=BN_set_word(bne,e);
    r=RSA_new();
    ret=RSA_generate_key_ex(r,bits,bne,NULL);
    if(ret!=1)
    {
        printf("RSA_generate_key_ex err!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    RSA_free(r);
    return 0;
}
```

The link errors:

```
\libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c|| undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'|
\libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c|| undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'|
\libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c|| undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleBitmap@12'|
\libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c|| undefined reference to `GetObjectA@12'|
\libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c|| undefined reference to `GetDIBits@28'|
\libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c|| undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'|
```

What's wrong?

Comment: you need link with `gdi32.lib`

Comment: @RbMm How to do that?

Comment: how add lib file to linker input ? if use link.exe - simply and add in command line or vs settings. if you use another linker - you must better know your native linker

Comment: `CreateCompatibleBitmap` (and friends) are only available in Desktop Apps. What type of Windows 10 app are you building? Also see [`CreateCompatibleBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183488(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Looking at the OpenSSL sources, it looks like OpenSSL 1.0.2 uses those functions for [`rand_win.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable/crypto/rand/rand_win.c). OpenSSL 1.1.0 does not use those functions. Maybe you can use OpenSSL 1.1.0 instead of 1.0.2. Also see [Configure 1.0.2 for Windows without readscreen()](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2017-July/006111.html) on the OpenSSL mailing list.